# Readonly textboxes are missing from Request.Form collection

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In one of my page, I have few text boxes which are set to readonly based on the user selection. All of these buttons are missing from the Request.Form collection, during postback.

I have no idea why it is happening. But, I tried few things.

a) disabling or setting the text box to readonly mean control will be missing from postback collection.
b) if view state is set to true, then only the first read only control is posted. others still fail.
c) tried manually enabling the control right before postback. no change.

So, here I am trying to find some ideas to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The successful control is posted to the server. Disabled control is not a successful control, however readonly controls are treated as successful, in general.
You can also open browser debugger and see the network header to view submitted elements for that particular request/form submission.
You may refer [w3org specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out. System was treating the readonly controls as unsuccessful ones, because some idiot disabled the view state in page attributes. No idea, why a page that needs postback should have that attribute. But, after removing that attribute, request.form works now. 

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with that network header thing.